# I want to see if player is on or below enemy in godot

Tags: collision-detection, godot

I want To see if my player is on top or beside the enemy in Godot. I want to kill the player if he goes beside the spider and kill the spider if the player jumps on it. my player and enemy are both KinematicBody2D's. I know how to kill the player or enemy(`queue_free()`) except I cannot detect if the player is on top or below the player. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Have you tried using a `Area2D` to detect when the player is beside the enemy? For jumping on the enemy, you could use a `RayCast2D` pointing down from the player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [CollisionShape2D](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_collisionshape2d.html#class-collisionshape2d-property-one-way-collision)
you can enable `one_way_collision` for both player and enemy choose collision way (top in your case), if it colides from the top just use `queue_free()`